# Mathjax strangely render back-tick in code blocks

Tags: mathjax, gist, backticks

I have a TCL code gist embedded in my own website. This page uses MathJax 2.7.5 configed with "TeX-MML-AM_CHTML". However, Mathjax strangely rendered the code between back-ticks in the comments of the code. For example, one line in the source code is (can be found [here in gist](https://gist.github.com/Hanlin-Dong/5c8dad37592527b5e514417ae9adc552#file-smartanalyze-tcl-L87)):

```
#   `testPrintFlag`  : integer
```

The letters "int" were rendered by MathJax to a integration symbol (see [here](http://www.hanlindong.com/en/2019/opensees-converge/#SmartAnalyze-Code-Download)).

The gist code block appears [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR1XK.png), but the correct one should be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlwNG.png). I'm wondering how I can fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file `TeX-MML-AM_CHTML` includes the AsciiMath input processor, and AsciiMath uses back-ticks as its math delimiters.  So all your back-tacks will cause AsciiMath to process their contents as math.  If you aren't using AsciiMath input, you probably want to use a different configuration format, like just `TeX-AMS_CHTML` which only does TeX input (not MathML and AsciiMath, as in your original).  That will be faster as well as it is a smaller file.

If you *are* using AsciiMath input, then you could configure it to use a different delimiter.  See [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/preprocessors/asciimath2jax.html) for details.

You could also configure MathJax to skip containers with certain class names (e.g., `class="gist"`).  See the `ignoreClass` option for the `asciimath2jax` preprocessor at the link above.  There is a similar one for the `tex2jax` preprocessor.